# Using UIViewPropertyAnimator to drive animation along curved path?

Tags: swift, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have an interruptible transition that is driven by UIViewPropertyAnimator and I would like to animate a view along a non linear path to its destination.

Doing some research I've found that the way to do this is by using:
`CAKeyframeAnimation`. However, I'm having issue coordinating the animations also I'm having issue with the CAKeyframeAnimation fill mode.
It appears to be reverse even though I've set it to forwards.

Below is the bezier path:

```
let bezierPath = self.generateCurve(from: CGPoint(x: self.itemStartFrame.midX, y: self.itemStartFrame.midY), to: CGPoint(x: self.itemEndFrame.midX, y: self.itemEndFrame.midY), bendFactor: 1, thickness: 1)

func generateCurve(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint, bendFactor: CGFloat, thickness: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    let center = CGPoint(x: (from.x+to.x)*0.5, y: (from.y+to.y)*0.5)
    let normal = CGPoint(x: -(from.y-to.y), y: (from.x-to.x))
    let normalNormalized: CGPoint = {
        let normalSize = sqrt(normal.x*normal.x + normal.y*normal.y)
        guard normalSize > 0.0 else { return .zero }
        return CGPoint(x: normal.x/normalSize, y: normal.y/normalSize)
    }()

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: from)

    let midControlPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + normal.x*bendFactor, y: center.y + normal.y*bendFactor)
    let closeControlPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: midControlPoint.x + normalNormalized.x*thickness*0.5, y: midControlPoint.y + normalNormalized.y*thickness*0.5)
    let farControlPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: midControlPoint.x - normalNormalized.x*thickness*0.5, y: midControlPoint.y - normalNormalized.y*thickness*0.5)


    path.addQuadCurve(to: to, controlPoint: closeControlPoint)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: from, controlPoint: farControlPoint)
    path.close()
    return path
}
```

Path visualization:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
containerView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Here's the CAKeyframeAnimation that resides inside of the UIViewPropertyAnimator

```
let curvedPathAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
curvedPathAnimation.path = bezierPath.cgPath
curvedPathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
curvedPathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
curvedPathAnimation.duration = animationDuration
self.attatchmentView.layer.add(curvedPathAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

So far this animation along the correct path, however the animation reverse back to it's starting position and is not in sync with the property animator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the fill mode. Now check to see whether you’ve drawn the bezier path in the right direction.

Comment: @matt I'm a little confused on what you meant by check whether or not I've drawn the bezier path in the right direction. If you mean whether or not the path is the intended path, then it is. Also I removed the fill mode and it still rebounds back to its starting position.

Comment: A path has directionality. If you think we’re traversing the path in the wrong direction, you drew the path in the wrong direction. — You have concealed all the relevant code (the path drawing, the property animator, etc) so it’s impossible to be more specific.

Comment: @matt updated question.

Comment: But I still don’t see any property animator, and if you had one you would not say `self.attatchmentView.layer.add`. A property animator  is a view animator, and it takes care of the animation.